# Problema ao fazer merge

Tags: git, codificação-de-caracteres, merge

estou realizando merges, e nessa ação, caracteres com acentos estão sendo trocados por símbolos, eu ainda não sei qual é a fonte do problema, se é o encoding dos arquivos , ou se o problema é no git , alguém pode me ajudar?
Abaixo está um exemplo de código que aconteceu  após eu relizar um merge entre duas branches.

**Ex**

```
log.warn("Tentou pegar anexos de análise inexistente");

log.warn("Tentou pegar anexos de an�lise inexistente");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está vendo um arquivo com a acentuação correta e outro com a acentuação incorreta no mesmo merge, provavelmente não é um problema com o Git.

O Git pode alterar a forma de quebra de linhas dos arquivos (CRLF vs LF), mas não altera a acentuação.

É bem provável que alguém comitou um arquivo com o encoding incorreto. Verifique a origem do arquivo com a acentuação com problema e, se preciso, peça para o desenvolvedor que fez a alteração acertar o encoding da sua IDE de desenvolvimento.

Comment: O problema é exatamente este, encoding diferentes , no repositório do git UTF-8  na IDE  CP1252. Ao visualizar o arquivo após merge de modificações a IDE não reconhece os acentos. Obrigado